# Proving that measure of a set is bounded by a norm

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$. Fix an $\epsilon>0$. Let $g$ be in $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $\|f-g\|_1\lt \epsilon$.

Consider the set $E=\{x\in \mathbb R^n: \lim_{r\to 0+}\frac 1{|B(x,r)|}|\int_{B(x,r)} f(y)- g(y) dy|\gt a/2\}$ for some $a>0$. $|X|$ denotes Lebesgue outer measure of the set $X\subset \mathbb R^n$.

Then, it is to be proven that $|E|\le c\|f-g\|_1$ for some constant $c$.

If $F:=\{x\in \mathbb R^n:  \exists r>0, \|f-g\|_1\gt a/2 |B(x,r)|\},$ then clearly, $E\subset F\implies |E|\le |F|$. Not sure, how to go from here.

Comment: There is a classical estimate used to prove the Lebesgue Differentiation theorem: $$|\{x : \sup_{r > 0}\frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}\int_{B(x, r)}|f(y)|\,dy > \lambda\}| \leq \frac{3^n}{\lambda}\|f\|_{L^1}.$$ See page 96 of "Real Analysis" by Folland.

Comment: @Kakashi: Thanks a lot :-). This answers my question.